relatedTo craft 5 nested matrix entires
Im trying to query a list of matrix entries that have a related field but it doesn't work after updating to craft 5. Note that 'category' is not category field type, its a regular structured entry type.
{% set relatedDetails = entry.details
    .type('customDetails')
    .relatedTo({
        targetElement: block.category.one(),
        field: 'category'
    })
    .all()
%}

returns 0 elements. However:
{% set unassignedDetails = entry.details.category(':empty:').all()%}

this works as intended, returning all nested entries that does not have that field assigned.
How can I do it?

Actually it was as simple that Craft 5 migration automatically renamed some fields that had the same handle in matrixes. (fieldName2 for example). So renaming in code and field type in control panel and making sure everything matches, fixed this.
